# About the trace operator and matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, expected-value

Suppose we have a matrix $T$ with dimension $N$x$N$,  As we know that $E(TT^H) = tr(TT^H)$ where $E(.)$ denotes the expected value, $(.)^H$ indicates the conjugate transpose, $tr(.)$ is the trace operator.

In case if we multiplied  $(TT^H)$ with different permutation matrices, the results of  $tr(TT^H)$ will be changed also to have minimal and maximal values.

What I need to check, what's about if the $T$ is diagonal matrix, that means that multiplcation of $(TT^H)$ with such permutation matrices gives $tr(TT^H)$ = $0$. Is that right?

Comment: What can you find out for $T=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\mu\end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes, that what I mean,  it means that will give zero,  but now the same case if $T$ is full rank, right ?

Comment: By "multiplication of $TT^H$ with a permutation matrix" do you mean $PTT^H$ or $P^{-1}TT^HP$ ? Because in the latter case: the trace is invariant under conjugacy.

Comment: I mean in the first case  $PTT^H$

Comment: Try to see what happens if you have block matrices 
$T=\begin{pmatrix}T_0&\\&T_1\end{pmatrix}$ and
$P=\begin{pmatrix}P_0&\\&\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}^{n-2}}\end{pmatrix}$ where 
$T_0=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\mu\end{pmatrix}$, $P_0=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $T_1$ is diagonal.
Then you should get $\operatorname{tr}(PTT^H) = \operatorname{tr}(T_1T_1^H)$ which isn't necessarily zero if $\operatorname{rank}(T_1)>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this question closable here is a couterexample which I alluded to in the comments:

Suppose $T=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}$ and
$P=\begin{pmatrix}&1&\\1&&\\&&1\end{pmatrix}$.
Then $\operatorname{tr}(PTT^H)=\operatorname{tr}(P)=1\neq0$.